# Snowflake File Format Error with Character

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have an immense CSV file that is separated by semi colon `;`, every column is enclosed by double quotes `"` but I've encountered cases when this happen:

```
....";"hello";"@!!xy;abc";"goodbye";...
```

A semi colon inside a string.
My current file format is like this:

```
TYPE = csv
FIELD_DELIMITER=';'
SKIP_HEADER = 1
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD ='\\';
```

If I add the `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'` condition, it gives me others errors, any thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if you already tried doing that and what happened then

Comment: @FelipeHoffa hi Felipe, yeah i tried adding the field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' but gives me the following error: Found character 'S' instead of field delimiter ';'

File 'xxx.csv.gz', line 14645, character 465
  Row 14644, column "yyy"["$56":56]

I download the csv, open and went to the line 14644 (14645 cause of the header) and in that position or for that column theres nothing strange or bad that i could tell at least

Comment: @FelipeHoffa actually, the data looks like this

;"SANTA MARTA 236 SN";"BOTILLERIA DON LUIS";"SANTIAGO";

The one in the middle is the column 56

Comment: It will be hard to debug this looking at just one line

Comment: yeah, i think the best scenario here is to modify the datastage that generates the csv file and clean those ; inside the column or just change the delimiter to | or something like that, a real shame