# Snowflake - Error with semi colon in CSV file format

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hello i have a CSV file that is separated by semi colon ;, every column is enclosed by double quotes " but I've encountered cases when this happen:

```
....";"word1";"@!!xy;abc";"word2";...
```

A semi colon inside a string. My current file format is like this:

```
TYPE = csv
FIELD_DELIMITER=';'
SKIP_HEADER = 1
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD ='\\';
```

If I add the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' condition, it gives me others errors, something like this:

Found character 'S' instead of field delimiter ';' File 'xxx.csv.gz', line 14645, character 465 Row 14644, column "yyy"["$56":56]

I downloaded the CSV, search for that line 14645 and theres nothing strange or bad that i could tell at least. The data looks like this ;"SANTA MARTA 236 SN";"BOTILLERIA DON LUIS";"SANTIAGO"; The one in the middle is the column 56

, any thoughts?

Comment: question may have been answered before, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058478/s3-to-snowflake-loading-csv-data-in-s3-to-snowflake-table-throwing-following-e

Comment: I see it's the same question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336879/snowflake-file-format-error-with-character, but it doesn't give us more data to be able to reproduce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake File Format Error with Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336879/snowflake-file-format-error-with-character)